# Why isn't this local script running?

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a local script that doesn't seem to be running. The functions aren't being called and it doesn't print anything when I try that.

```
local btn = game.StarterGui.Stages.Frame.F1
local btn2 = game.StarterGui.Stages.Frame.B1

local players = game:GetService("Players")
local plr = players.LocalPlayer
local val = plr.CurrentStage

btn.MouseButton1Up:Connect(function()
    val.Changed:Connect(function()
        if val == 29 then
            local char = plr.Character
            local hrp = char:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
            hrp.Position = script.Parent.Position + Vector3.new(0, 2.5, 0)
        end
    end)
end)
```

I'm making an obby game and I'm trying to add the ability to go back in stages. I'm trying to teleport the player using scripts but they're not running at all. Earlier I tried to use a server script and remote events but that wasn't working so I then tried a local script with a list of all the stages but that didn't work either. I tested this script by making print statements and none of them ran, I even made the entire script just one print statement and it wasn't running at all.

Comment: Where is this LocalScript located?

Comment: It's inside the checkpoint